# promise-sftp hangs after 'put'

Tags: node.js, file-upload, promise, ssh2-sftp

I am working on a NodeJS component uploading a file to an SFTP server using `promise-sftp` version 0.11.3. I am basically doing these steps:

```
const PromiseFtp = require('promise-sftp');
const ftp = new PromiseFtp();
await ftp.connect(...);
await ftp.put(imageBuf, './subdir/fileName');
await ftp.end();
```

I ensured that all the steps are working correctly up to `put`. `imageBuf` is a Buffer object storing binary image data. I have these effects which I don't understand:

- The `put` returns a `WriteStream` object. But [the documentation](https://github.com/realtymaps/promise-sftp#readme) states: "Returned promise resolves to undefined."
- The file is not uploaded correctly as it has a size of 0, even though the Buffer has the correct size.
- The `end` call does not return anymore.
- Passing the image's filename to `put` results in the call not returning anymore (even though the file is uploaded correctly in this case).
- Using a `.then` chain results in the same issue (obviously?).

I already tried to put a `ftp.stat` call right after the `put`. Doing so results in not returning from the `stat` call anymore. I have another function calling `ftp.unlink` instead of `put` which is working correctly. That's why I guess that the `put` call is the culprit.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any way I can debug my code to see what's happening/what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation, I realized that the uploaded image was also cut-off when passing a filename to `put`. I tried to output debug information (using the `debug` argument passed to the `connect` call), but I could not see any useful hints for resolving my issue.

Reading the documentation of the `promise-sftp` package, I realized that the last update as well the the latest issues are over 3 years old with the documentation not being updated since version 0.9.0. As some issues are tagged with "help wanted" my guess is, that the package is not being maintained actively.

So I finally switched to the package `ssh2-sftp-client`, which is quite up to date. I did not even have to change the code (only the `require` argument, obviously) and the upload is now working flawlessly.